# Agreggate rows on dataframe with python

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

I have a big parquet file, that have many rows with repeated fields:

| client_identifier_1 | client_identifier_2 | value_a | value_b | product_identifier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | c | 12 | 22 | au |
| a | c | 11 | 12 | au |
| a | c | 5 | 12 | au |
| b | a | 4 | 21 | ag |
| b | a | 3 | 1 | ag |

I need to sum and transform value_a and value_b rows where client_identifier_1, client_identifier_1 and product_identifier matches.

expected output:

| client_identifier_1 | client_identifier_2 | value_a | value_b | product_identifier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | c | 28 | 46 | au |
| b | a | 7 | 22 | ag |

Answer (score 2):

Groupby and agg

```
df.groupby(['client_identifier_1','client_identifier_2','product_identifier']).agg('sum').reset_index()
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is going using this?

Comment: All I do is to groupby the columns in the list. I then find the aggregate sum. What pandas does is it sums all the other remaining columns individually per groups specified in the columns specified in the list.

Comment: This dataframe contain other columns, but i just need to sum value_a, and value_b.
Have a way to explicit sum just this fields?

Comment: Please try from the following based on what you want `s =df.groupby(['client_identifier_1','client_identifier_2','product_identifier'])[['value_a','value_b']].agg('sum').reset_index()` or

`df[['value_a','value_b']] =df.groupby(['client_identifier_1','client_identifier_2','product_identifier'])[['value_a','value_b']].transform('sum')
df=df.drop_duplicates()`